# Kotlin array literal syntax like java

Tags: java, kotlin, syntax, new-operator

Just a simple question

when we will get array literal syntax in kotlin like java

```
var array = arrayOf<Int>(1,2,3,4,5) // current syntax
```

```
var array = {1,2,3,4,5} // new syntax
```

If any of you have information on the current status of this feature or if it has already been implemented in a newer version that I might have missed, I would greatly appreciate your insights. Additionally, any tips or workarounds for achieving a more compact syntax while working with arrays in Kotlin would be welcome.

Comment: As a minor frame challenge, in Kotlin lists are much more common than arrays. Lists are collections and so have access to all the extensions and other places where collections can be used; they have multiple implementations; they work better with generics; and they they usually have better toString() and comparison and other method implementations. Arrays are needed for interoperability, for varargs, and for low-level implementation of other structures, but for everything else lists are preferable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That specific syntax with curly brackets I think will never happen because it's too close to the Kotlin syntax for lambdas. For example, it would break existing code like:

```
val x = { 1 } // type of x is inferred to be () -> Int
```

However, they are at least considering it with square brackets. That can be followed [here in the official YouTrack issues list](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-43871). This issue was opened by the lead Kotlin designer, so it's not just wishful thinking from a random user. Unfortunately, there is no planned implementation date yet.

A couple of possibilities for shortening it:

The `<Int>` in your code is redundant and can be dropped, because the type can be inferred by the compiler when the array is not empty.

You can use a function alias like

```
import kotlin.arrayOf as a
```

so you could write code like

```
val x = a(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

in files where you create a lot of literal arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin does not have an array syntax (varray = {1,2,3,4,5}). To create an array in Kotlin, you must use a function such as arrayOf or intArrayOf.

```
val array = intArrayOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Comment: The OP is aware the syntax does not now exist; he is asking 'when' it will exist.